# ATG plugin for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, atg

where can i find ATG plugin for eclipse?

even i tried this [url](http://atgeclipse.sourceforge.net/)

But i was not able to install in eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

As of ATG 10, the plugin is included with ATG and is located in the Eclipse folder (./ATG10.1.2/Eclipse/ATGUpdateSite.jar). Load that into Eclipse and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can find information about ATG plugin for Eclipse in ATG [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/ATGInstallGuide/html/s0108installingatgdevelopmenttoolsfor01.html).

The one which you try to install seems to be for ATG Dynamo, which is quite old server.

**EDIT**

It appears that this documentation regarding Eclipse plugin is not longer valid.

Oracle provides another ATG plugin which comes in as a package with ATG **10.1.1** as stated [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10543653) (not available to download separately).

Comment: i m using eclipse indigo Version: 3.7.1. i cant find those steps in eclipse.

Comment: @rijana, which steps do you refer to? The ones from ATG documentation?

Answer (score 0):

It usually available in the installation itself. I tried and doesn't really comfortable using that. Not sure there are active development of eclipse plugins to support latest versions of eclipse.